# split() not working after first line in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, split

When running this code segment:

```
for(int i=0; i<np; i++){
        giver=f.readLine();
        String[] numbers=f.readLine().split("\\s");
        System.out.println(giver+" "+numbers[0]+" "+numbers[1]);
```

It gives the output of the fires line correctly but afterwards gives the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at gift1.main(CopyOfgift1.java:47)
```

I'm new to Java and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. All help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

EDIT : The input is of the following format

```
amy 
600 5 
jane 
477 9 
clara 
599 3
```

Comment: that says you have a line getting read that you assume has at least two numbers separated by whitespace, which does not have 2 values.

Comment: Is there a newline at the end of the file?  This would appear to be an empty line, and the `split()` call would return an array of length 1 in this situation.

Comment: Can you add your input data and the value of np? It is hard to know what's going on without these

Comment: Editterd to add the input data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this loop to figure out what is going on:

```
for(int i=0; i<np; i++){
        giver=f.readLine();
        String assumedNumbers = f.readline();
        try {
            String[] numbers =f.readLine().split("\\s");
            System.out.println(giver+" "+numbers[0]+" "+numbers[1]);
        }
        catch ( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
            System.out.println( "INVALID NUMBERS LINE '" + assumedNumbers + "'" );
            throw( e );
        }
}
```

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks:). It was a problem with the input rather than the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading linbes too much, then.
Be sure you are not exceeding number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

use following modified code.

```
for(int i=0; i<np; i++){
        giver=f.readLine();
        String[] numbers=giver.split("\\s");
        System.out.println(giver+" ");
        for(String s:numbers)  //inhance for loop
        {
            System.out.println(" "+s);  
        }
}
```

If `giver` doesn't contain white-spaced string then you will not get output but you will never get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.